# Whatif Analysis with Measure

Tags: powerbi

I have created a What-if analysis where i am deciding the Threshold value to it.

I have an margin% and Actual Margin % and i need to compare both these value with the value of the Threshold.

Like, Threshold= 20%

margin= 3.90%

Actual Margin %= 0.65%

So, i have created a measure where i am calculating the Actual Margin % with Threshold value i.e. x=0.65*20%

Now i need to compare it(x) with the margin i.e. if(margin

I am able to get this both the measure in place but unable to get the final measure with color code.

Note: Threshold level can be changed and the x value should be changed accordingly with the final color code as well.

[image]

Comment: Can you please show what you have so far, your measure that is.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Parameter called Threshold: min 1 max 100 step 1 (create also the slider by setting the radio button)

```
Threshold = GENERATESERIES(0; 100; 1)
```

Create a measure:

```
Measure = if (SUM('Values'[ Value]) > Threshold[Parameter Value];"Green";"Red")
```

Add the measure to the table visual and go to the format tool. Go to conditional formatting. select the measure from the combo and set the Background color on.[image]

Now you get a popup. Set to field value and the column to measure.

Result: when sliding your values will change:

[image][image]